# Icinga error "Icinga Startup Delay does not exist" although it does

Tags: startup, icinga

I just installed icinga to monitor my server following this guide:
http://docs.icinga.org/0.8.1/en/wb_quickstart-idoutils.html

Everything built and installed correctly, but icinga is reporting a critical error with the reason: "The command defined for service Icinga Startup Delay does not exist"

However, I can see that ${ICINGA_BASE}/etc/objects/localhost.cfg contains:

```
define service{
    use                             local-service   ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Icinga Startup Delay
    check_command                   check_icinga_startup_delay
    notifications_enabled           0
}
```

and ${ICINGA_BASE}/etc/objects/commands.cfg contains:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_icinga_startup_delay
    command_line    $USER1$/check_dummy 0 "Icinga started with $$(($EVENTSTARTTIME$-$PROCESSSTARTTIME$)) seconds delay | delay=$$(($EVENTSTARTTIME$-$PROCESSSTARTTIME$))"
}
```

both of these files had not been modified since the whole make/install process.

I am running on Ubuntu 10.04, most recent build of icinga-core, and apache2 2.2.14

What must I do to tell Icinga that the command exists?  Or is the problem that check_dummy does not exist?  Where or how would I define that?

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into the same problem. It turns out that following directory has no read permission for other group:

```
# ls -ld /usr/local/libexec/nagios/
drwxr-x---  2 root  wheel  1536 May 28 15:20 /usr/local/libexec/nagios/
```

The reason for that was because I have set a stricter umask in my ~/.cshrc:

```
# cat ~/.cshrc
umask 27
```

Change the permission of the directory solving the problem:

```
# chmod 755 /usr/local/libexec/nagios/
```

Verify all the nagios plugins have the read permission as well:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/libexec/nagios
```

Answer (score 0):

1) verify that $USER1$ macro points to a valuable location. check resource.cfg and docs.icinga.org for that

2) verify that the nagios plugins package is installed (and providing check_dummy binary) e.g. via

```
# dpkg -l *nagios-plugins*
```

3) verify that $USER1$ points to where nagios-plugins are installed (default: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins)

4) make sure to check other resources for help as well - http://www.icinga.org/support/
luckily someone else pointed here...